# Compare the values in two columns to update the third column in a database using C# program

Tags: c#, .net-core, comparison, razor-pages

There are four categories(Economics, Technology, Extracurricular and quality) and several courses offered under each of the four categories. A student can pick any course from one of the four categories according to their preference. 
And their preference must be compared with their history ie. whether or not they have taken a course in that category before, and a priority point in internally generated and stored in the database along with other value.

For example: If a student has already taken a course under Technology and he again picks technology then the corresponding priority point is 0. Whereas if he has never taken a course in that category before, the priority point is 40.

This is the code I have written for that but it is throwing an error and I am not sure how to resolve.

C# code:

```
public class AddPreferenceModel : PageModel
    {

        public CUser User { get; set; }
        public CStudent Student { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public CPreference Preference { get; set; }
        public COffers Offers { get; set; }

        private readonly IHostingEnvironment _environment;
        private readonly CDataContext _context;
        private readonly IEmailService _emailServices;
        private readonly IUserService _UserService;

        public AddPreferenceModel(IUserService UserService, CDataContext context, IHostingEnvironment IHostingEnvironment, IUserService IUserService, IEmailService emailService)
        {
            _environment = IHostingEnvironment;
            _ntUserService = ntUserService;
            _context = context;
            _emailServices = emailService;

            User = _UserService.GetUser();
        }

        public CHistory History { get; set; }
        public IList<CPreference> Pref { get; set; }
        public IList<CHistory> Hist { get; set; }
        public IList<COffers> Off { get; set; }
        public IList<CStudent> stud { get; set; }

        public ActionResult OnGet()           
        {
            if (User.Role != Role.Admin && User.Role != Role.Student)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("/Denied");
            }

            return Page();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

             if(Preference.Category == History.History)
                    {
                        Preference.Priopoints = Priopoints.zero;
                        _context.Preference.Add(Preference);
                        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                    }
              else
                    {
                        Preference.Priopoints = Priopoints.high;

                        _context.Preference.Add(Preference);
                        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    }
                }
            }

            return RedirectToPage("IndexPref");
        }
    }
```

I am getting an error at  `if(Preference.Category == History.History)`

The error is

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.'

I am working on .net Framework using C# (razor page). Any help on how to improvise or rectify the error will be appreciated.

Edit: 
HTML code

```
<div class="Custom-Content Custom-Max-Width-800">
    <h2 class="h2">Add your preference</h2>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="orderForm" method="post">
        <div class="col-md-12"><hr /></div>
        <h4 class="h4 Custom-H4-Less-Margin-Bottom">Preference</h4>
        <div class="Custom-Form col-sm-6">
            NTUser
            <input asp-for="Preference.StudentUser" type="text" value="" required="" />
        </div>

        <div class='col-md-12'><hr /></div>
        <div class="Custom-Form col-sm-4">
            Course Name
            <input asp-for="Preference.name" type="text" value="" required="" />
        </div>
        <div class="Custom-Form col-sm-4">
            Category
            <select asp-for="Preference.Category" required>
                <option value="Wirtschaft">Wirtschaft</option>
                <option value="Technik">Technik</option>
                <option value="Qualität">Qualität</option>
                <option value="Überfachlich">Überfachlich</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="Custom-Form col-sm-4">
            Priority
            <select asp-for="Preference.Priority" required>
                <option value="High">High</option>
                <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
                <option value="Low">Low</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: how are you accepting the category which student has selected? there is no model in the post method.

Comment: It is a form that the student's fill out. The variables for it are under the class preference. Look at the edit for more details. :) 
The html code stores it in the respective places. The code works fine if I remove the if else statement keeping the _context.Preference.Ass(Preference), await _context.SaveChangesAsync() and return RedirectToPage("IndexPref") 
But when I try to compare with the history and try to add it shows error.

Comment: Either Preference or History is null, else they both are. Did you debug the project to check which one it is?

Comment: Neither are null. I had encountered the similar error with another class as well but it turned out I had not added BindProperty. So my guess is that it has nothing to do with the Object being null but something else.